# Auth0 Lock login view failing in iOS app with error: -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "org-appextension-feature-password-management://"

Tags: ios, swift, auth0

I'm trying to get Auth0 iOS SDK to work. I've followed everything in their getting started guide and successfully am able to display their custom login view with `Lock`:

```
func initiateAuth0Login() {
  Lock
    .classic()
    .withStyle {
      $0.title = "Conference Planner"
    }
    .onAuth { credentials in
      if let idToken = credentials.idToken {
        self.handleSuccessfulLogin(idToken: idToken)
      }
    }
    .onError {
      print("Failed with \($0)")
    }
    .present(from: self)
}
```

I have included my domain and client ID in `Auth.plist`.

I'm getting the following error in the console when the login view is displayed:

```
2017-09-04 12:21:33.570 ConfPlanner[90651:24225579] 
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "org-appextension-feature-password-management://"
- error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

Through googling for the error message, I found that I needed to add `org-appextension-feature-password-management` as a value for `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in my `Info.plist`. I did that but I'm still getting the error...

[image]

any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue and did not find any solution. Given the fact that adding the URL to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in info.plist (as you did) is supposed to solve the issue and does not with Auth0- should we request a bug ticket on GitHub?